# Integrate HaxeFlixel on webpage

Tags: web, html, haxe, haxeflixel

I am developing a little game that i will have to run in a normal HTML5 web page that is hosted. Any idea about how I can do this?.

I've searched for a lot of time but still can't get an answer. I did run the game in Chrome, but it was using the Flixel's CLI and VS Code (http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/visual-studio-code/).I have to run it in my hosted webpage.

I'm pretty sure it is posible to do this because in the oficial page there are some demos uploaded. Some use flash (http://haxeflixel.com/demos/Colors/) and some others don't. It will be perfect for me to not use flash, but at this point, if I run it with flash, it will be great anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the haxeflixel demo page web source code to see how they do it?  You could just copy the contents of the `..\export\html5\bin` directory of your project into your website source tree.  The contents however are a full-fledged web-page, so if you're looking to run within a view on a page you may have to place it in an iframe.  This is all a very manual process though.